# Asp.net core on azure issue with loading static files

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, static-files

We have an `asp.net core` application hosted in `azure` as web-app. 
We have pretty big front-end including few javascript files, images and html.
And sometimes, request for a static files(for instance something.js) just runs into endless process and replies after long delay with status `502 Bad Gateway`. It happens not often, but it is a big problem for us. All our static files are placed under the `wwwroot` directory.

Have someone experienced something similar?

Comment: Do you have the same issue if running locally?

Comment: Unrelated question: If you have a big/high traffic page and use azure, why not host static files on the CDN instead? Do you have many small files or few big ones?

Comment: @Tseng . I have ng2 application and I am using webpack minification strategy, so I dont have huge amount of *.js files. Also, I don't have big traffic, on my webapp.

Comment: @alltej. No, I am not able to reproduce it locally.

Comment: Is the static files middleware at the top of the app pipeline?

Comment: @NateBarbettini Yes, I just use - `app.UseStaticFiles();` without any special constructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So ok, after few days of investigation together with team we came up with next solution. We have updated version of ASP.NET Core to 1.1 and the problem was solved. This problem cannot be reproduced when you deploy your application on local-IIS only on azure.

I am not sure, which team of MS have produced that bug(azure team or ASP.NET core team). But it is sad that quality of MS products have dramatically decreased during last 2-3 years.

So don't blame your self too much when some unknown bug appears in your code, probably it is a gift from MS. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems this issue is well documented and should be addressed in the upcoming .NET Core 1.1.1 patch (set to be released tomorrow, 03/07/2017).

https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/311